# What's the default storage for Google Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

There is not documentation that I can find about the storage that Google Cloud Run has. For example, does it contains few Gigabyte storage as we create a VM?
If not, is there a '/tmp' folder that I can put data temporarily into during the request? What's the limitation if available?

If neither of them available, what's the recommendation if I want to save some temporary data while running Cloud Run?

Answer (score 26):

Cloud Run is a stateless service platform, and does not have any built-in storage mechanism.

Files can be temporarily stored for processing in a container instance, but this storage comes out of the available memory for the service as described in the [runtime contract](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#filesystem). Maximum memory available to a service is 8 GB.

For persistent storage the recommendation is to [integrate with other GCP services](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-gcp-services) that provide storage or databases.

The top services for this are [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) and [Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/).

These two are a particularly good match for Cloud Run because they have the most "serverless" compatibility: horizontal scaling to matching the scaling capacity of Cloud Run and the ability to trigger events on state changes to plug into asynchronous, serverless architectures via [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/) and Cloud Storage's [Registering Object Changes](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reporting-changes) and [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions) with Cloud Function [Events & Triggers](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers).

Answer (score 23):

The writable disk storage is an in-memory filesystem, which limited by instance memory to a maximum of 8GB. Anything written to the filesystem is not persisted between instances.

See:

- https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas
- https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#filesystem
- https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#memory