# How to mount persistent storage to Google Cloud Run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I was trying to run a Docker image with Cloud run and realised that there is no option for adding a persistent storage. I found a list of services in https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-gcp-services#connecting_to_services_in_code but all of them are access from code. I was looking to share volume with persistent storage. Is there a way around it ? Is it because persistent storage might not work shared between multiple instances at the same time ? Is there are alternative solution ?

Answer (score 14):

Cloud Run is serverless: it abstracts away all infrastructure management.

Also is a managed compute platform that automatically scales your **stateless containers.**

> Filesystem access The filesystem of your container is writable and is
> subject to the following behavior:
>
> This is an in-memory filesystem, so writing to it uses the container
> instance's memory. Data written to the filesystem does not persist
> when the container instance is stopped.

You can use Google Cloud Storage, Firestore or Cloud SQL if your application is **stateful**.

[3 Great Options for Persistent Storage with Cloud Run](https://medium.com/google-cloud/3-great-options-for-persistent-storage-with-cloud-run-f1581ee05164)

[What's the default storage for Google Cloud Run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55908257/whats-the-default-storage-for-google-cloud-run)

Answer (score 12):

Having persistent storage in (fully managed) [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run) should be possible now.
Cloud Run's [second generation execution environment](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-execution-environments) (`gen2`) supports [network mounted file systems](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/using-network-file-systems).

Here are some alternatives:

1. **Cloud Run + GCS**: [Using Cloud Storage FUSE with Cloud Run tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse)
2. **Cloud Run + Filestore**: [Using Filestore with Cloud Run tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-filestore)

If you need help deciding between those, check this:

- [Design an optimal storage strategy for your cloud workload](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/storage-advisor?hl=en#decision_tree)

> NOTE: At the time of this answer, Cloud Run gen2 is in Preview.

Answer (score 5):

Cloud Run (fully managed) has known services that's [not yet supported](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#unsupported-services) including Filestore which is also a persistent storage. However, you can consider running your Docker image on Cloud Run Anthos which runs on GKE and there you can use [persistent volumes](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/persistent-volumes#persistentvolumes) which are typically backed by Compute Engine persistent disks.

Comment: I thought Anthos is used when you are using a multi-cloud environment.

Comment: Yes that's correct. You install Cloud Run for Anthos on a GKE cluster and that cluster (Anthos) can run on cloud or on-prem but take note that this is just an alternative that I can come up with. If you're interested, you can check out the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/prebuilt-deploy-gke) guide.

Answer (score 1):

As of early 2024, it is possible to mount volumes to Cloud Run containers !

You can either mount a [Cloud Storage Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/cloud-storage-volume-mounts), which uses [Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) in the background to sync your files. You should be aware of the performance and concurrency issues that you will encounter, but in many read-only cases, it works perfectly.

You can also mount an [In-memory Volume](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/in-memory-volume-mounts), which you can use to either limit the amount of memory per instance, or share between instances.

These features are currently in beta.