# Have you found a way of persisting the odoo core modules in v14 different form a volume? And so, it is possible deploying odoo in gcloud run?

Tags: odoo, google-cloud-run

I want to deploy odoo as cheap as possible. I tried with gcloud sql (15-30€/m) + cloud run. But after some minutes passed the odoo interface shows me a white screen with so many logs in the console similar to this:

```
GET 404 1.04 KB24 ms Chrome 91 https://bf-dev3-u7raxlu3nq-ew.a.run.app/web/content/290-f328144/1/website.assets_editor.css
```

My interpretation is that, as cloud run is stateless, and the web static files seems to be stored in the core module, after the container is killed this information is lost. As I've been one month working looking for a solution, before trying any another way of deploying I ask the community: **Have you found a way of persisting the odoo core modules in v14 different form a volume? And so, it is possible deploying odoo in gcloud run?**

Here I listed all the ideas that I tried:

- First, I thought that this css files were store in the werkzeug session, so I tried two addons that stored this session in a place different from the filestore. These addons were camptocamp odoo-cloud-platform-14.0/session-redis and misc-addons-13.0/base_session_store_psql. But, then the problem persisted.
- Then I read that the static css and js file generated in the web editor are stored in odoo as attachments, and the addons misc-addons-13.0/ir_attachment_s3 could store these files in s3. But, although I configured this addon the problem persisted.
- Next, I found [this link](https://reedrehg.medium.com/odoo-images-and-attachments-explaining-and-regenerating-assets-d1eb7fe8a3ed) describing needing to regenerate assets so them to be stored in the db. But, although I did that the problem persisted.
- Finally, I thought to deploy odoo in other ways. The way of directly in a vm seems to be the more minimalistic and standard, and so seem to have the more chances to work, although it will be difficult to implement gitops. It can be deployed containers in the vm through docker compose what will help deploying updates. Gke anthos seems to implement gitops too and seems to [persist volumes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64228967/how-to-mount-persistent-storage-to-google-cloud-run), but in the description it shows gke anthos is stateless. Finally, there's the way of deploying in a k8s cluster, this way will implement containers and allow autoscaling vs the docker compose way in a vm. But it's true it seems to be more expensive and more difficult to implement. Regarding seem to be more expensive it is thought of trying little working nodes machines so the cost stays small during the night. Regarding the difficulty of deploying, it is desired to implement gitops so it seems argo or other should be added. Also, I heard gke autopilot has a good free tier and is easier to deploy.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Run isn't the good solution for that. Indeed, if the werkzeug session is persisted in memory, the same client isn't sure to access to the same instance each time, and thus to lost the file even in the middle of a session.

The best solution is to use VM with sticky session configuration. You can use old school deployment on Compute Engine, or Cloud Native solution with GKE/K8S. It's more or less the same cost if you have only 1 cluster (the first one is free)

---

Just a correction about GKE Anthos. I think you talk about Cloud Run on Anthos, and yes, it's like Cloud Run but use KNative on GKE to manage the containers, and it's also serverless. But GKE can handle stateful deployment, as you need with odoo

Comment: I have one final doubt @guillaumeblaquiere: then, as far as I'm understanding the point, odoo can be deployed in compute engine but autoscaling groups won't be useful, as there will be no way of linking one vm data with other new vm data. But in case of K8s it seems it can work, as with the volume concept data could be shared between instances. Isn't it?

Comment: Load balancer + VM is roughly equal to GKE/K8S deployment: the technical constraint are the same, only the deployment/management part are different. Therefore, you can use the same disk between several VM, but only in read only. It's the same with GKE. Except if you use a NAS compliant system, such as Filestore service, that allow you to perform read and write from different VM (or PODs, it's the same solution with GKE)